# isatty() always returning False?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to pipe data via stdin to a Python script for onwards processing. The command is:

```
tail -f /home/pi/ALL.TXT | python3 ./logcheck.py
```

And the Python code is:

```
import sys

while 1:
    if (sys.stdin.isatty()):
        for line in sys.stdin:
            print(line)
```

I want the code to continuously watch `stdin` and then process each row when received. The `tail` command is working when run on its own but the python script never outputs anything.

Checking `isatty()` it appears to always return `False`?

Help!

Comment: Because stdin isn't a tty when you pipe stuff into it. Why would you expect this to return true?

Comment: Other tutorials suggested isatty is true when piped, false otherwise. How else can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TTY is when you use your regular terminal - as in opening up a python in your shell, and typing

```
BASH>python
>>>from sys import stdin
>>>stdin.isatty() #True
```

In your case the standard input is coming from something which is not a `tty`. Just add a `not` in the `if` statement.

Comment: FYI , `* * * * * /Users/username/isatty_test.py >> /Users/username/isatty_test.log` in crontab will show False as it is expected.